# Crawling urls from multiple sitemap.xml files

Tags: apify

I'm building an apify actor for a page where all the needed urls  are stored in different sitemap.xml-files. The file names are static, but can't figure out how to add several sitemap.xml files to the actor.

Down below are the working code with 1 xml-file. Somehow needs to either do a for-each on multiple urls, but as there are about 600 of them, it would preferably by something like extracting all sitemaps from a csv, and then crawl each for urls, and then crawl each url.

```
const Apify = require('apify');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const requestPromised = require('request-promise-native');

Apify.main(async () => {

    const xml = await requestPromised({
        url: 'https://www.website.com/sitemap1.xml’, // <- This part needs to accept input of about 600 sitemap.xml urls in total

        headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'curl/7.54.0'
        }
     });

    // Parse sitemap and create RequestList from it
    const $ = cheerio.load(xml);
    const sources = [];
    $('loc').each(function (val) {
        const url = $(this).text().trim();
        sources.push({
            url,
            headers: {
                // NOTE: Otherwise the target doesn't allow to download the page!
                'User-Agent': 'curl/7.54.0',
            }
        });
    });

    const requestList = new Apify.RequestList({
        sources,
    });
    await requestList.initialize();

    // Crawl each page from sitemap
    const crawler = new Apify.CheerioCrawler({
        requestList,
        handlePageFunction: async ({ $, request }) => {

            await Apify.pushData({
                url: request.url
            });
        },
    });

    await crawler.run();
    console.log('Done.');
});
```

Each sitemap.xml has a static link/name, but their content is changing daily, and the total amount of urls in the sitemaps are 60-70.000, its those urls that I ultimately needs to fetch :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most reliable way to do this is to use the power of [Apify Crawler classes](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/examples/basiccrawler). There are of course many ways to handle this problem.

The simplest solution would be to use one `CheerioCrawler` and have separate logic in `handlePageFunction` for sitemap URLs and the final URLs. Unfortunately, `CheerioCrawler` is not able to parse XML (probably will be fixed in near future) so we will have to use 2 crawlers.

For the first part of XML parsing, we will use `BasicCrawler`. It is the most generic of Apify's crawlers so it can easily use the code you already have. We will push the extracted URLs to a [requestQueue](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/requestqueue) and handle them in the second crawler which can stay mostly as it is.

```
const Apify = require('apify');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const requestPromised = require('request-promise-native');

Apify.main(async () => {

    // Here we will push the URLs found in the sitemaps
    const requestQueue = await Apify.openRequestQueue();

    // This would be better passed via INPUT as `const xmlUrls = await Apify.getInput().then((input => input.xmlUrls))`
    const xmlUrls = [
        'https://www.website.com/sitemap1.xml',
        // ...
    ]

    const xmlRequestList = new Apify.RequestList({
        sources: xmlUrls.map((url) => ({ url })) // We make smiple request object from the URLs
    })

    await xmlRequestList.initialize();

    const xmlCrawler = new Apify.BasicCrawler({
        requestList: xmlRequestList,
        handleRequestFunction: async ({ request }) => {
            // This is basically the same code you have, we just have to push the sources to the queue
            const xml = await requestPromised({
                url: request.url,
                headers: {
                    'User-Agent': 'curl/7.54.0'
                }
            });

            const $ = cheerio.load(xml);
            const sources = [];
            $('loc').each(function (val) {
                const url = $(this).text().trim();
                sources.push({
                    url,
                    headers: {
                        // NOTE: Otherwise the target doesn't allow to download the page!
                        'User-Agent': 'curl/7.54.0',
                    }
                });
            });
            for (const finalRequest of sources) {
                await requestQueue.addRequest(finalRequest);
            }
        }
    })

    await xmlCrawler.run()

    // Crawl each page from sitemap
    const crawler = new Apify.CheerioCrawler({
        requestQueue,
        handlePageFunction: async ({ $, request }) => {
            // Add your logic for final URLs
            await Apify.pushData({
                url: request.url
            });
        },
    });

    await crawler.run();
    console.log('Done.');
});
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot! The first part worked flawlessly with multiple xml's! How should the INPUT be formatted for it to work? Tried different variations of: 

{
 "url": [{
   "url": "https://www.sitemap1.xml"
  },
  {
   "url": "https://www.sitemap2.xml"
  }
 ]
}

Comment: Happy to help. Try it like this: 
INPUT.json can have a structure like this:
```{
    xmlUrls: ["https://www.website.com/sitemap1.xml", "https://www.website.com/sitemap2.xml"]
}```
Then you can load it with the code I showed in the input
`const input = await Apify.getInput();`
`const { xmlUrls } = input;`